# Graphene and relativistic dynamics

Tags: special-relativity, condensed-matter

Is it possible to rewrite the **Lorentz-transformations** (for quantum particles) in terms of **effective mass m*** known from condensed matter physics?

["From pencil lead to relativistic quantum physics"](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~kane/html-physics/pedagogical/295lec1.pdf)

["A Mechanism for the effects of Relativity"](http://webspace.qmul.ac.uk/rocornwall/A%20Mechanism%20for%20Relativity.pdf)

[Matter_waves#Four-vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_waves#Four-vectors)

Comment: Any help to rewrite this question in a more precise manner would be highly appreciated. The starting point for this question was the cited article "A Mechanism for the effects of Relativity" Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to disappoint you, but the second "article" you are citing is the usual pseudo-science nonsense published by the crank crowd. I would suggest you pick up half a dozen good textbooks on relativity and study the introductory chapters until you understand the experimental difference between relativity and ether models. It's the only way to get past the mental block that exists in the human mind to getting over our evolved intuitive understanding for the Galilean metric, which, fortunately, is not how the world works (if it was, the world couldn't exist, to begin with!).

It takes time. In case of my personal experience it took several attempts at special and general relativity to "grock" the difference, which is profound.

Having said that, while many problems in condensed matter physics can be approached with techniques from field theory, the similarities of solid state systems to the physical vacuum are limited. The similarity of carrier transport in graphene to relativistic motion, in particular, is limited to a narrow energy range. In contrast, the consequences of relativity to the daily world (i.e. your existence in particular), require that relativity holds over an extremely large range of scales, which is probably well beyond 50 orders of magnitude.

Comment: Hi, the author of the second article is a postgraduate in the Engineering and Material Science Department of the University of London. So in terms of academic hierarchy he has more to say about physics, than me.

Comment: What I am interested in, are the overlapping areas of definition. Let me quote Diels, "The Power and Precision of Light", p. 3: _"The minimum energy state of the quantum harmonic oscillator is not zero, but
(1/2)hν. This is often referred to as vacuum fluctuation or zero point
energy. The absence of vacuum (the ether concept) has been replaced
by an absence of zero energy. Since, according to Einstein, there is
an equivalence of matter and energy, the two concepts are not so far
apart."_

Comment: So given the relativistic dispersion relation, (see first cited article), can we find an akin concept to the Lorentz-transformation in Condensed Matter language. Sorry for this very vague ideas.

Comment: @user22207: Education and titles from educational institutions, no matter how good, do not stop people from going off on a tangent that misses reality by a fair amount. Judging from my personal experience (and this is COMPLETELY anecdotal), engineers (EE, CS) are especially prone to misunderstanding the fundamental symmetry properties of Maxwell's Equations.

Comment: @user22207: Having said that, one can find solid state systems which MIMIC relativistic mechanics in a narrow energy range. That doesn't make them relativistic as a simple excitation with phonons (fancy language for sound waves) or the application of an external magnetic field would show, both of which would immediately break the approximate Lorentz symmetry of the material.

Comment: But still it would be interesting to see, what in special relativity can be rewritten in terms of effective mass m* and concepts from solid state mechanics. The question which in the first place got me interested in the article by Remi Cornwall is: Can we find yet another formulation of special relativity inspired by the math of other branches of physics, no matter in which way the math was used originally? (Field-theoretic techniques are certainly used in an entirely different way in condensed matter physics than in other branches of physics.) @CuriousOne

Comment: No offense, but I think you are trying to approach the horse from the wrong end. All of field theory is a consequence of special relativity, not the other way around. The world is not relativistic, because it has a certain underlying "crystal structure". Quite the contrary, nuclei and atoms and electrons and photons only exist, because the underlying symmetry group is the Lorentz group. Take that symmetry away, and nothing that you know, including yourself, can even exist. The universe would either be empty or it would be in one lump, but it couldn't form any structures.